# Looking for a theory predicting conductivity values of electrolytes at higher concentrations

Tags: concentration, conductivity

I'm looking for a theory to calculate the electrical conductivity of electrolytes, namely $\ce{NaCl}$ and tartaric acid ($\ce{C4H6O6}$) dissolved in water, depending on their concentration.

The only equation I could find was the one derived from the Debye-Hückel theory, which I read works great for 1:1 electrolytes like $\ce{NaCl}$ (not sure about tartaric acid 1:2 electrolyte), but only until about 0.1 M.

The concentrations in my case vary from 0.2 M up to 4.0 M.

Is there a theory I can use to calculate conductivities in that range, or is the Debye-Hückel theory the only one?

Comment: Related: [Conductivity as a function of acid concentration](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26781/conductivity-as-a-function-of-acid-concentration/).