# Determining the concentration of ammonium nitrate by chemical means

Tags: concentration, titration

I have several litres of ammonium nitrate solution that I do not know the concentration of, but is approximately 0.6M. I don't have precise enough instruments to determine it via its density. I titrated it with NaOH, since the ammonium ion is a weak acid, but it is too weak and the endpoint is impossible to discern clearly. I then realised of course I could just evaporate the water and weigh the solute, but the question still stuck with me: how could I determine its concentration by chemical means? The only other way I can think of is to measure its conductance and compare this value to existing data.

Comment: Try adding a precise amount to excess standard NaOH, carefully distilling off the ammonia and titrating the remaining NaOH with HCl.

Comment: If you have a good balance and a 100 ml volumetric flask you can determine the density of the solution directly.

Comment: @MaxW, I tried that but the values I got are way off -- less dense than pure water. The balance is only to 2 d.p. so I suspect it is not good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the solution is *pure*, your idea of making standardized $\ce{NH4NO3}$ solutions and comparing conductance should work.

*Caveat:* This works as long as conductivity vs. concentration is a [monotonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). For some other substances is *not*, e.g., for $\ce{H2SO4}$, which, at STP, has a [distinct peak in conductance at ~30%](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153107/why-does-the-graph-of-the-electrical-conductivity-of-sulfuric-acid-water-solutio), and then drops off, so that there are *two* points on the curve at which conductivity is the same, but concentration quite different.

This is also the case for $\ce{NH4NO3}$ above 8.0 m/mol kg<sup>-1</sup>, but, in [the region in which you are interested](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Isotherms-of-electrical-conductivity-of-aqueous-ammonium-nitrate-solutions-at-three_fig3_237382805), it should not be an issue.

However, there is another, simpler, rather old alternative: **use a hydrometer**. The density of $\ce{NH4NO3}$ *is* a monotonic function. And others have already done the work for you, [charting density against concentration](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Variation-of-density-with-concentration-of-aqueous-ammonium-nitrate-solutions-at-29815-K_fig1_237382805).

<sub>[***Eureka!***](https://www.bellarmine.edu/learningcommunity/eureka/about/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you @DrMoishe. I have learned something new about monotonic functions!