# Can we add specific conductivities at any concentration?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, conductivity

Suppose we have specific conductivities of $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{K+}$ and $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{Cl-}$. Can we add their specific conductivities to get specific conductivity of $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{KCl}$?

Comment: We can, but the problem is usually the other way around. Specifically, KCl  of various molarity is used as conductivity standard to calibrate conductometers.

Comment: Conductivity is not necessarily a linear function, particularly at high concentrations. See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26781/conductivity-as-a-function-of-acid-concentration For example, there's a reduction at high NaCl concentrations, though KCl is more linear over that range.

Comment: No, you can add molar conductivities of ions only in a _dilute regime_. This is also known as [Kohlrausch's law of independent migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_conductivity#Kohlrausch's_law_of_independent_migration_of_ions).